# toggling variable inside Module Pattern using function declaration vs function expression

Tags: javascript, module-pattern, function-expression, javascript-function-declaration

I have a module pattern with a variable setting the currentPlayer to 1. I use a function expression to toggle that variable

```
 const game = (() => {
    let currentPlayer = 1;

    const toggleCurrentPlayer = () => {
        if (currentPlayer == 1){
            currentPlayer = 2 ;
        }
        else {
            currentPlayer = 1;
        }
    };
    return {currentPlayer, toggleCurrentPlayer};
})();
```

If I run `game.currentPlayer` it logs 1, I then run `game.toggleCurrentPlayer()`, and it doesn't change `currentPlayer` as intended, it still returns 1.

However, changing the `toggleCurrentPlayer()` function using `this`, seems to be able to change the variable successfully

```
function toggleCurrentPlayer(){
    if (this.currentPlayer == 1){      
        this.currentPlayer=2;
    }
    else if (this.currentPlayer == 2){
        this.currentPlayer=1;
    }
};
```

I know function declarations and function expressions have different meanings for the keyword `this`, but why would the `toggleCurrentPlayer()` only work properly with the `this` keyword and not be able to set the variable on its own?

Comment: The difference has nothing to do with the way `toggleCurrentPlayer` is declared. It's about modifying a local variable vs. modifying an object property.

Comment: @Bergi So I can only modify the object property inside the module, but I cannot assign a new value to the variable inside the module?

Comment: Your first code does toggle the local variable just fine. The problem is that the `game.currentPlayer` property is not a live view on the variable, it just keeps the value that you created initially.

Comment: (And you've got it backwards: any code from outside the module can assign the object property using `game.currentPlayer = 3;`, but only the code inside the module scope can access and assign the local variable `let currentPlayer`)

Comment: I wonder how he can change the currentPlayer variable inside game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the function does

```
return {currentPlayer, toggeleCurrentPlayer};
```

It copies the initial value of the `currentPlayer` variable into the object.

The returned object contains the value of the variable, not a reference to the variable itself. Reassigning the variable has no effect on the object.

What you can do instead is create an object inside the function, and modify that.

```js
const game = (() => {
  let obj = {
    currentPlayer: 1,
    toggleCurrentPlayer: () => {
      if (obj.currentPlayer == 1) {
        obj.currentPlayer = 2;
      } else {
        obj.currentPlayer = 1;
      }
    }
  };
  return obj;
})();

console.log(game.currentPlayer);
game.toggleCurrentPlayer();
console.log(game.currentPlayer);
```

Another way to do it is with a getter function that retrieves the variable.

```js
const game = (() => {
    let currentPlayer = 1;

    const toggleCurrentPlayer = () => {
        if (currentPlayer == 1){
            currentPlayer = 2 ;
        }
        else {
            currentPlayer = 1;
        }
    };
    const getCurrentPlayer = () => currentPlayer
    return {getCurrentPlayer, toggleCurrentPlayer};
})();

console.log(game.getCurrentPlayer());
game.toggleCurrentPlayer();
console.log(game.getCurrentPlayer());
```

Comment: In that case you wouldn't even need the IIFE

Comment: Without the IIFE where would I get a scope for `obj`? I could change it to use `game.currentPlayer` in the toggle function.

Comment: Oops, I missed that you had not used `this` in a method but an arrow function closing over `obj`. But yeah, given that `game` is `const` anyway, using that seems fine as well.

Comment: The getter function approach seems more appropriate though, here, and nicely demonstrates the issue that the OP had.

Comment: I see some pegagogical value to separating the external variable from the internal code.

Comment: that was very helpful, can you just help me understand why the the getter function works?

Comment: It's accessing a variable saved in the closure.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work